# Calculation of a new field with conditions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.6

I am struggling with the calculation of a new field that is based on another field.

I have one field with numbers that appear twice (`"Field_A"`) and I need to calculate a new field (`"Field_B"`) that has the value `-90` when one number appears the first time and the value `90` when the same number appears the second time.

[image: Attribute_table]

I am working with ArcGIS 10.6. I guess I need a Python code block.

Comment: Maybe you can do a conditional statement with the unique ID field. Something like If(ID=even, set field_b to 90, else set it to -90).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data looks like your screenshot there is no need to use Field_A, Field_B just needs to be filled with -90,90,-90,90 etc.. Try this in Python Window of ArcGIS:

```py
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\feature_class' #Change
field = 'Field_B'

givemenumbers = iter([-90,90]*1000000)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row=next(givemenumbers)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

If that does not work this should, with any number count and order of Field_A values. Pandas [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) will number each item in each group, and -90 or 90 will be calculated depending on even or odd numbering using if/else with list comprehension:

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
fc = 'Pointsample' #Change
field_a = 'Field_A' #Change
field_b = 'Field_B' #Change

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field_a), columns=[field_a])
values = iter([-90 if v%2==0 else 90 for v in df.groupby(field_a).cumcount().tolist()])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,field_b) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row=[next(values)]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: As always, brilliant!

Comment: @nora no problem! could you accept my answer with the checkbox?

Comment: Testing now the second code with other point data, I always receive the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/XXX/YYY/VVV/BBB/AAA_WWW20112018.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field_a), columns=[field_a])
RuntimeError: cannot open 'Pointsample'

I cannot understand the problem, because everything is there. Guess it is something with the workspace?

Comment: @nora. You need to change pointsample to the name of your feature class. Where do you execute the code, inside ArcMap? If so add your layer to the map and change Pointsample in the code to the name of your layer

Comment: My mistake was the use of the alias name of the field, as it was readable in the table… sorry for asking